# Unable to bind webgrid in mvc4 using jquery

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am not able to get data in my webgrid.
This is my controller code.

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<tm_grp_group> pm = db.tm_grp_group.ToList();
            return View();

        }

        //
        // GET: /GroupMaster/Details/5
        public JsonResult GetAllData()
        {
            List<tm_grp_group> tm = db.tm_grp_group.ToList();
            return Json(tm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        public void SaveNew(string grp_name, string grp_description, bool grp_isactive)
        {
            tm_grp_group tm = new tm_grp_group();
            tm.grp_name = grp_name;
            tm.grp_description = grp_description;
            tm.grp_isactive = grp_isactive;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void DeleteById(int grp_id)
        {
            tm_grp_group pro = db.tm_grp_group.First(x => x.grp_id == grp_id);
            db.tm_grp_group.Remove(pro);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void UpdateEdit(int grp_id, string grp_name, string grp_description, bool grp_isactive)
        {
            tm_grp_group pro = db.tm_grp_group.First(x => x.grp_id == grp_id);
            pro.grp_id = grp_id;
            pro.grp_name = grp_name;
            pro.grp_description = grp_description;
            pro.grp_isactive = grp_isactive;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        public JsonResult GetDataById(int grp_id)
        {
            tm_grp_group pro = db.tm_grp_group.First(x => x.grp_id == grp_id);
            return Json(pro, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my view code.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function ViewAll() {
    ///////////  Fetch all Method   /////////////
    $('#tblgrpmaster tbody').html('');
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'GroupMaster/GetAllData',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: 'grp_id' },
        success: function (ashdata) {
            var items = '';
            $.each(ashdata, function (i, item) {

                var rows = "<tr>"
                            + "<td >" + item.grp_id + "</td>"
                            + "<td >" + item.grp_name + "</td>"
                            + "<td >" + item.grp_description + "</td>"
                            + "<td >" + item.grp_isactive + "</td>"
                            + "<td ><a href='#' onclick='GetDataEdit(" + item.grp_id +
                            ");'>Edit</a> | <a href='#' onclick='Delete(" + item.grp_id + ");' title='" + item.grp_id + "'>Delete</a></td>"
                            + "</tr>";
                $('#tblgrpmaster tbody').append(rows);
            });

        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    ViewAll();
});
<table>
    @Html.Hidden("grp_id")
    <tr><td>Group Name : </td><td>@Html.TextBox("grp_name")</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Group Description : </td><td>@Html.TextBox("grp_description")</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Group IsActive : </td><td>@Html.TextBox("grp_isactive")</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><a href="#" id="Save" onclick="SaveNew();">Save</a></td></tr>
</table>


    <table id="tblgrpmaster">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="left" >
                    GroupID
                </th>
                <th align="left" >
                    Group Name
                </th>
                <th align="left" >
                    Group Description
                </th>
                <th align="left">
                    Group IsActive
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

Due to space issue i have not copied to saved edit delete code here. Whenever first run i index action method i want to display data in view. But i am not able to get data in webgrid. May i know ehere i am going wrong here?

Comment: Check your console. you will definitely find error there. action not found

Comment: I did not get. I am running index action method. I cant figure out any error in jquery nor in controller

Comment: Data is not binding. That Viewall method is not executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'GroupMaster/GetAllData',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (ashdata) {
        var items = '';
        $.each(ashdata, function (i, item) {

            var rows = "<tr>"
                        + "<td >" + item.grp_id + "</td>"
                        + "<td >" + item.grp_name + "</td>"
                        + "<td >" + item.grp_description + "</td>"
                        + "<td >" + item.grp_isactive + "</td>"
                        + "<td ><a href='#' onclick='GetDataEdit(" + item.grp_id +
                        ");'>Edit</a> | <a href='#' onclick='Delete(" + item.grp_id + ");' title='" + item.grp_id + "'>Delete</a></td>"
                        + "</tr>";
            $('#tblgrpmaster tbody').append(rows);
        });

    },
   error: function(e)
   {
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
   }
});
```

As you can see, GetAllData doesn't accept any parameter and it is also HttpGet method, so need to change type to get and remove data part

Comment: Yes. How can i make changes here?

Comment: Still I am not recieving any data in webgrid. I did as you told.

Comment: Can you put debugger and check that you GetAllData action is getting call or not?

Comment: No getalldata action is not calling.

Comment: put the error code also in ajax. and check that ViewAll function is getting called or not by putting alert

Comment: Index method is getting call. and             List<tm_grp_group> pm = db.tm_grp_group.ToList();
 pm will get desired value. but i want to get data in getalldata.

Comment: Index Action is just returning view. So issue is related getAllData action

Comment: yes. issue with GetAllData. Also viewall function is not getting call.

Comment: try with closing script tag, you forget to close it

Comment: Hi, now its working fine. But whenever i add data it should display in table below. But its appending to the table. for example if i had 3 records previously now if i insert new record it will display 7 records including previous 3 and new one.